# Discontinous graph - ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot command to graph my data. I get this picture:

[image]

The graph is ugly and discontinus; I look at another data and it looks like this: 
[image]

(Their code is in Step 2 on link: https://www.datascience.com/blog/introduction-to-forecasting-with-arima-in-r-learn-data-science-tutorials). How do I make my data look like that?

My code is:

```
daily_data = read.csv2('satni3.csv', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

daily_data$Date = as.Date(daily_data$datum, format = "%Y.%m.%d")

ggplot(daily_data, aes(Date, total)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date('day') + 
  ylab("opterecenje") + 
  xlab("") # total is the column with numbers that represent some data for a given date.
```

Here is half of my data (there is 15 days missing), pasted, first are names of columns and then there is data:

```
datum;sat;a11;a21;a31;b11;b21;b31;b41;b51;c11;c21;xx1;a12;a22;a32;b12;b22;b32;b42;b52;c12;c22;xx2;sum1;sum2;total
01.01.2017;00:00;0;16;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;62;4;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;16;68;84
01.01.2017;01:00;0;76;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;79;3;82
01.01.2017;02:00;0;151;3;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;15;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;156;16;172
01.01.2017;03:00;0;72;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;19;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;73;20;93
01.01.2017;04:00;0;32;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;18;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;33;18;51
01.01.2017;05:00;0;22;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;15;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;25;15;40
01.01.2017;06:00;0;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;12;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;7;13;20
01.01.2017;07:00;0;10;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;14;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;10;15;25
01.01.2017;08:00;0;9;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;11;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;9;11;20
01.01.2017;09:00;0;12;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;15;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;12;17;29
01.01.2017;10:00;0;15;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;21;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;18;23;41
01.01.2017;11:00;0;37;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;28;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;38;31;69
01.01.2017;12:00;0;59;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;78;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;61;81;142
01.01.2017;13:00;0;70;0;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;3;88;4;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1;73;97;170
01.01.2017;14:00;1;123;5;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;110;3;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;130;114;244
01.01.2017;15:00;3;101;0;0;0;0;0;0;6;0;0;1;124;4;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;110;130;240
01.01.2017;16:00;0;128;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;117;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;131;120;251
01.01.2017;17:00;1;126;2;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;99;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;130;102;232
01.01.2017;18:00;0;91;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;84;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;93;86;179
01.01.2017;19:00;0;69;2;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;53;4;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;73;58;131
01.01.2017;20:00;0;54;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;42;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;54;45;99
01.01.2017;21:00;0;36;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;22;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;38;25;63
01.01.2017;22:00;0;11;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;19;2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;13;22;35
01.01.2017;23:00;0;15;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;12;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;17;14;31
02.01.2017;00:00;0;13;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;10;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;13;11;24
02.01.2017;01:00;0;11;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;12;2;14
02.01.2017;02:00;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;2;6;8
02.01.2017;03:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
02.01.2017;04:00;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;7;2;9
02.01.2017;05:00;0;3;2;0;0;0;0;1;2;0;0;0;3;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;8;6;14
02.01.2017;06:00;0;8;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;7;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;1;9;11;20
02.01.2017;07:00;0;29;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;1;37;1;0;0;1;0;0;3;0;0;31;43;74
02.01.2017;08:00;0;60;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;75;5;3;1;2;0;0;1;0;0;62;87;149
02.01.2017;09:00;0;54;1;2;2;4;0;0;1;0;0;0;62;3;5;1;2;1;1;0;0;0;64;75;139
02.01.2017;10:00;0;52;7;1;1;9;1;0;1;0;0;0;63;4;2;1;7;0;0;1;0;0;72;78;150
02.01.2017;11:00;0;76;5;5;0;6;0;1;2;0;0;0;81;5;2;2;7;0;1;0;0;0;95;98;193
02.01.2017;12:00;0;86;6;6;0;10;0;1;0;0;0;0;79;9;1;1;9;0;3;2;0;0;109;104;213
02.01.2017;13:00;0;92;2;2;2;4;0;0;2;0;0;0;69;3;0;3;7;0;1;0;0;0;104;83;187
02.01.2017;14:00;0;104;2;3;2;9;0;1;0;0;0;0;99;7;3;4;5;1;1;1;0;1;121;122;243
02.01.2017;15:00;0;117;8;0;1;11;0;0;1;0;0;0;85;2;0;1;11;0;0;2;0;0;138;101;239
02.01.2017;16:00;0;113;4;0;0;6;0;0;4;0;0;0;95;1;2;0;8;0;0;3;0;0;127;109;236
02.01.2017;17:00;0;115;3;2;0;3;0;0;2;0;0;0;114;3;0;0;5;0;0;1;0;0;125;123;248
02.01.2017;18:00;0;61;1;1;1;1;0;1;0;0;0;0;94;4;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;66;101;167
02.01.2017;19:00;0;72;4;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;57;3;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;77;61;138
02.01.2017;20:00;0;33;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;45;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;36;47;83
02.01.2017;21:00;0;21;1;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;32;4;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;24;40;64
02.01.2017;22:00;0;22;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;24;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;23;26;49
02.01.2017;23:00;0;23;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;20;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;25;20;45
03.01.2017;00:00;0;12;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;8;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;13;9;22
03.01.2017;01:00;0;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;7;4;11
03.01.2017;02:00;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;1;5
03.01.2017;03:00;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;1;3
03.01.2017;04:00;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;2;4
03.01.2017;05:00;0;3;1;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;7;4;11
03.01.2017;06:00;0;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;3;2;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;8;7;15
03.01.2017;07:00;0;25;2;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;51;5;0;1;0;0;1;2;0;0;29;60;89
03.01.2017;08:00;0;64;4;1;1;5;0;0;0;0;0;1;86;4;4;1;2;1;0;2;0;0;75;101;176
03.01.2017;09:00;0;65;4;2;3;6;0;0;1;0;0;0;57;8;5;0;7;0;0;1;0;1;81;79;160
03.01.2017;10:00;0;84;13;3;3;8;1;2;1;0;0;0;75;9;1;0;5;0;0;0;0;1;115;91;206
03.01.2017;11:00;0;74;3;3;1;6;0;2;1;0;0;0;75;7;1;3;4;0;0;0;0;0;90;90;180
03.01.2017;12:00;1;96;10;3;3;9;0;0;0;0;1;1;85;6;5;1;7;0;0;0;0;0;123;105;228
03.01.2017;13:00;1;115;9;5;0;1;0;0;1;0;1;0;103;7;2;2;6;0;0;1;1;1;133;123;256
03.01.2017;14:00;2;120;8;3;0;6;0;0;1;0;3;0;114;6;2;1;5;0;0;1;0;0;143;129;272
03.01.2017;15:00;0;116;6;1;0;7;0;0;1;0;0;1;107;5;1;0;6;0;0;3;0;0;131;123;254
03.01.2017;16:00;0;139;4;0;0;5;0;0;4;0;0;0;115;5;1;0;4;0;0;2;0;0;152;127;279
03.01.2017;17:00;0;117;1;2;0;4;0;0;1;0;0;0;126;5;0;2;5;0;0;1;0;0;125;139;264
03.01.2017;18:00;0;86;4;1;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;86;4;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;92;92;184
03.01.2017;19:00;0;57;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;70;3;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;60;76;136
03.01.2017;20:00;0;40;4;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;48;3;2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;46;54;100
03.01.2017;21:00;0;37;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;37;3;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;39;43;82
03.01.2017;22:00;0;25;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;20;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;27;21;48
03.01.2017;23:00;0;23;0;0;0;1;0;0;2;0;0;0;14;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;26;14;40
04.01.2017;00:00;0;20;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;10;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;20;11;31
04.01.2017;01:00;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;1;5
04.01.2017;02:00;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;4
04.01.2017;03:00;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;2;3
04.01.2017;04:00;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;2
04.01.2017;05:00;0;4;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;5;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;7;7;14
04.01.2017;06:00;0;10;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;10;8;18
04.01.2017;07:00;0;31;3;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;1;43;6;0;1;1;0;0;3;0;0;36;55;91
04.01.2017;08:00;0;74;4;1;0;4;0;0;0;0;1;0;91;2;6;1;3;0;0;2;0;0;84;105;189
04.01.2017;09:00;0;65;10;2;2;7;0;0;1;0;0;0;73;8;3;1;8;0;0;1;0;0;87;94;181
04.01.2017;10:00;0;76;4;4;2;9;0;0;1;0;0;0;66;9;2;1;8;0;0;0;0;0;96;86;182
04.01.2017;11:00;1;94;1;3;2;7;0;1;1;0;0;0;89;4;2;2;8;0;0;0;0;0;110;105;215
04.01.2017;12:00;0;96;4;1;0;8;0;0;0;0;0;0;92;5;2;2;7;0;0;0;0;1;109;109;218
04.01.2017;13:00;1;98;4;3;1;3;0;0;1;0;0;1;100;10;4;5;5;0;0;2;0;0;111;127;238
04.01.2017;14:00;1;120;3;0;0;8;0;1;1;0;0;0;84;4;3;0;5;0;0;2;0;1;134;99;233
04.01.2017;15:00;0;114;3;1;1;4;0;0;1;0;0;0;109;5;0;1;7;0;1;2;0;1;124;126;250
04.01.2017;16:00;1;139;6;1;0;6;0;0;4;0;0;0;109;4;4;1;7;0;0;2;0;0;157;127;284
04.01.2017;17:00;1;115;5;3;0;7;0;0;1;0;0;1;124;5;0;0;8;0;0;1;0;0;132;139;271
04.01.2017;18:00;0;77;2;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;97;3;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;81;103;184
04.01.2017;19:00;0;51;4;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;57;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;57;58;115
04.01.2017;20:00;0;41;3;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;34;2;0;0;0;0;1;2;0;0;46;39;85
04.01.2017;21:00;0;24;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;38;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;27;42;69
04.01.2017;22:00;0;23;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;30;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;25;32;57
04.01.2017;23:00;0;16;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;14;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;18;14;32
05.01.2017;00:00;0;19;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;10;1;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;19;13;32
05.01.2017;01:00;0;9;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;9;1;10
05.01.2017;02:00;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;3;5
05.01.2017;03:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1
05.01.2017;04:00;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1
05.01.2017;05:00;0;4;1;0;0;1;0;0;2;0;0;0;4;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;8;6;14
05.01.2017;06:00;0;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;5;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;8;8;16
05.01.2017;07:00;0;30;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;1;49;5;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;33;59;92
05.01.2017;08:00;0;57;1;3;2;8;0;0;0;0;0;0;76;4;3;3;9;0;0;2;0;0;71;97;168
05.01.2017;09:00;0;64;4;4;1;12;0;0;1;0;0;0;59;6;2;1;9;0;0;1;0;0;86;78;164
05.01.2017;10:00;2;85;8;2;2;10;0;0;1;0;0;1;40;8;3;2;11;0;0;0;0;0;110;65;175
05.01.2017;11:00;0;86;9;6;2;8;0;0;2;0;0;0;91;6;5;3;11;0;0;0;0;0;113;116;229
05.01.2017;12:00;0;127;9;2;6;10;0;0;0;0;0;1;93;7;1;3;11;0;0;2;0;1;154;119;273
05.01.2017;13:00;0;105;5;1;2;4;0;0;3;0;0;0;107;9;3;3;5;0;0;0;1;1;120;129;249
05.01.2017;14:00;0;104;5;3;0;14;0;0;1;0;0;0;117;7;2;0;10;0;0;1;0;1;127;138;265
05.01.2017;15:00;0;117;5;1;0;10;0;0;1;0;0;0;107;6;3;0;10;0;1;3;0;1;134;131;265
05.01.2017;16:00;0;126;4;1;0;11;0;0;4;0;0;0;110;3;3;2;10;0;1;1;0;0;146;130;276
05.01.2017;17:00;0;132;4;0;1;10;0;0;1;0;0;0;118;1;2;0;13;0;0;0;0;0;148;134;282
05.01.2017;18:00;0;71;2;2;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;89;3;0;1;1;0;0;1;0;0;77;95;172
05.01.2017;19:00;0;57;5;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;57;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;64;60;124
05.01.2017;20:00;0;43;4;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;58;3;0;0;0;0;1;2;0;0;49;64;113
05.01.2017;21:00;0;36;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;50;1;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;38;55;93
05.01.2017;22:00;0;30;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;25;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;33;27;60
05.01.2017;23:00;0;17;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;22;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;20;23;43
06.01.2017;00:00;0;22;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;13;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;22;15;37
06.01.2017;01:00;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;6;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;7;12
06.01.2017;02:00;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;5;9
06.01.2017;03:00;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;5;7
06.01.2017;04:00;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;2;4
06.01.2017;05:00;0;5;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;8;7;15
06.01.2017;06:00;0;6;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;7;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;7;10;17
06.01.2017;07:00;0;7;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;21;4;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;8;27;35
06.01.2017;08:00;0;10;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;27;1;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;13;30;43
06.01.2017;09:00;0;15;3;1;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;24;1;2;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;21;28;49
06.01.2017;10:00;0;41;3;0;3;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;39;1;2;1;2;0;0;0;0;0;49;45;94
06.01.2017;11:00;0;61;3;1;1;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;52;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;68;54;122
06.01.2017;12:00;0;61;5;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;58;1;1;0;1;0;0;2;0;1;67;64;131
06.01.2017;13:00;0;73;4;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;59;1;1;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;78;63;141
06.01.2017;14:00;0;67;2;2;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;91;3;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;72;97;169
06.01.2017;15:00;0;93;4;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;78;2;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;98;82;180
06.01.2017;16:00;0;67;3;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;72;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;71;75;146
06.01.2017;17:00;0;73;1;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;59;2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;76;62;138
06.01.2017;18:00;0;59;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;61;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;60;64;124
06.01.2017;19:00;0;47;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;42;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;49;43;92
06.01.2017;20:00;0;31;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;28;1;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;32;31;63
06.01.2017;21:00;0;51;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;26;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;52;28;80
06.01.2017;22:00;0;16;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;19;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;17;19;36
06.01.2017;23:00;0;24;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;31;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;26;32;58
07.01.2017;00:00;0;12;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;9;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;13;11;24
07.01.2017;01:00;0;9;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;9;7;16
07.01.2017;02:00;0;2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;8;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;8;11
07.01.2017;03:00;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;4;6
07.01.2017;04:00;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;4;6
07.01.2017;05:00;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;7;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;8;12
07.01.2017;06:00;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;5;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;5;8;13
07.01.2017;07:00;0;7;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;28;5;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;10;36;46
07.01.2017;08:00;0;24;2;0;1;8;0;0;0;0;1;0;31;2;2;0;7;0;1;2;0;0;36;45;81
07.01.2017;09:00;0;32;5;1;3;11;0;0;1;0;0;0;30;2;3;1;16;0;0;1;0;0;53;53;106
07.01.2017;10:00;0;47;4;3;3;14;0;0;0;0;0;0;41;3;2;3;12;0;0;1;0;1;71;63;134
07.01.2017;11:00;0;83;5;3;2;12;0;0;1;0;0;0;54;2;2;1;9;0;0;0;0;0;106;68;174
07.01.2017;12:00;0;90;2;1;1;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;78;2;1;1;10;0;0;1;0;2;101;95;196
07.01.2017;13:00;2;84;3;2;2;6;0;0;1;0;0;0;81;5;3;0;7;0;0;1;0;1;100;98;198
07.01.2017;14:00;0;78;6;2;2;8;1;0;1;0;0;0;86;3;1;1;10;0;0;2;0;1;98;104;202
07.01.2017;15:00;0;92;3;2;4;8;0;0;0;0;0;0;81;3;1;1;10;0;0;1;0;2;109;99;208
07.01.2017;16:00;0;83;2;1;0;0;0;1;2;0;0;0;92;2;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;89;96;185
07.01.2017;17:00;0;69;2;1;1;3;0;0;1;0;0;0;83;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;77;84;161
07.01.2017;18:00;0;59;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;70;1;1;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;61;73;134
07.01.2017;19:00;0;38;2;1;0;1;0;0;2;0;0;0;42;1;3;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;44;48;92
07.01.2017;20:00;0;41;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;51;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;41;53;94
07.01.2017;21:00;0;22;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;31;2;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;25;35;60
07.01.2017;22:00;0;26;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;18;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;26;19;45
07.01.2017;23:00;0;26;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;16;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;28;17;45
08.01.2017;00:00;0;19;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;13;1;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;19;16;35
08.01.2017;01:00;0;9;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;8;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;9;8;17
08.01.2017;02:00;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;4;9
08.01.2017;03:00;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;4;5
08.01.2017;04:00;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;1;3
08.01.2017;05:00;0;2;2;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;5;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;5;7;12
08.01.2017;06:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;6;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;8;8
08.01.2017;07:00;0;9;2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;15;5;0;0;0;0;1;2;0;0;12;23;35
08.01.2017;08:00;0;16;1;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;16;0;1;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;22;20;42
08.01.2017;09:00;0;18;1;2;1;4;0;0;1;0;0;0;19;1;0;0;4;0;0;1;0;0;27;25;52
08.01.2017;10:00;0;49;1;1;1;5;0;1;1;0;0;0;30;1;0;0;5;0;1;0;0;0;59;37;96
08.01.2017;11:00;0;47;0;1;0;4;0;2;0;0;0;0;35;1;2;1;5;0;1;0;0;0;54;45;99
08.01.2017;12:00;0;79;2;1;0;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;52;2;0;0;6;0;0;1;0;0;89;61;150
08.01.2017;13:00;0;67;3;2;0;4;0;0;1;0;0;0;63;1;1;0;6;0;0;1;0;0;77;72;149
08.01.2017;14:00;1;74;3;2;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;85;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;81;88;169
08.01.2017;15:00;2;74;5;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;61;8;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;83;71;154
08.01.2017;16:00;0;65;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;81;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;69;82;151
08.01.2017;17:00;0;71;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;62;2;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;74;65;139
08.01.2017;18:00;0;55;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;61;0;0;2;0;0;0;2;0;0;55;65;120
08.01.2017;19:00;0;33;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;36;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;34;37;71
08.01.2017;20:00;0;42;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;38;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;43;40;83
08.01.2017;21:00;0;23;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;1;28;1;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;25;33;58
08.01.2017;22:00;0;22;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;20;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;22;22;44
08.01.2017;23:00;0;9;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;9;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;12;11;23
09.01.2017;00:00;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;5;9
09.01.2017;01:00;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;2;3
09.01.2017;02:00;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;2;7
09.01.2017;03:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1
09.01.2017;04:00;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;3;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;4;8
09.01.2017;05:00;0;2;1;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;6;3;9
09.01.2017;06:00;0;6;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;2;0;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;6;8;14
09.01.2017;07:00;0;42;0;1;0;1;0;1;2;0;0;0;50;6;1;1;0;0;0;3;0;0;47;61;108
09.01.2017;08:00;0;84;2;5;2;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;111;6;5;1;6;0;0;2;0;0;98;131;229
09.01.2017;09:00;1;66;5;0;0;9;0;0;1;0;0;0;74;4;8;2;6;0;0;0;0;0;82;94;176
09.01.2017;10:00;0;80;8;2;4;8;0;0;1;0;0;0;64;5;2;3;11;0;0;0;0;0;103;85;188
09.01.2017;11:00;1;80;3;8;2;6;0;2;2;0;0;0;76;7;2;4;7;1;1;0;0;0;104;98;202
09.01.2017;12:00;0;107;7;5;3;9;0;1;0;0;0;0;80;9;3;2;11;0;1;1;0;0;132;107;239
09.01.2017;13:00;0;103;8;3;1;5;0;1;1;0;1;0;76;6;3;2;8;0;0;1;0;0;123;96;219
09.01.2017;14:00;0;106;5;2;2;5;0;0;1;0;0;0;92;8;4;1;9;1;0;2;0;0;121;117;238
09.01.2017;15:00;0;97;8;4;1;8;0;0;1;0;0;0;104;2;5;4;7;1;0;2;0;0;119;125;244
09.01.2017;16:00;0;112;6;5;4;8;1;0;3;0;0;0;106;4;4;3;9;0;1;1;0;0;139;128;267
09.01.2017;17:00;0;109;6;3;3;7;0;0;2;0;0;0;129;6;1;0;8;0;0;1;0;1;130;146;276
09.01.2017;18:00;0;86;5;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;92;4;1;0;0;0;1;2;0;0;93;100;193
09.01.2017;19:00;0;47;2;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;60;3;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;51;64;115
09.01.2017;20:00;0;42;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;45;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;45;48;93
09.01.2017;21:00;0;38;2;0;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;0;34;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;42;36;78
09.01.2017;22:00;0;29;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;22;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;31;23;54
09.01.2017;23:00;0;17;2;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;25;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;21;25;46
10.01.2017;00:00;0;14;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;6;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;14;8;22
10.01.2017;01:00;0;8;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;8;4;12
10.01.2017;02:00;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;1;3
10.01.2017;03:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;1;2
10.01.2017;04:00;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;2
10.01.2017;05:00;0;7;0;0;0;0;0;1;2;0;0;0;5;1;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;10;8;18
10.01.2017;06:00;0;6;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;9;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;7;12;19
10.01.2017;07:00;0;38;3;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;49;7;0;1;1;0;0;3;0;0;43;61;104
10.01.2017;08:00;0;78;2;1;2;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;102;0;3;0;9;2;0;2;0;1;90;119;209
10.01.2017;09:00;0;85;9;2;3;8;0;0;1;0;0;0;91;6;3;2;11;0;0;0;0;0;108;113;221
10.01.2017;10:00;0;62;8;2;4;10;1;0;1;0;0;0;68;9;3;1;9;0;0;0;0;0;88;90;178
10.01.2017;11:00;1;100;11;4;4;9;0;0;2;0;0;0;80;10;6;1;9;0;0;0;0;0;131;106;237
10.01.2017;12:00;0;96;5;6;5;9;0;0;0;0;0;0;101;5;1;2;14;1;0;1;0;0;121;125;246
10.01.2017;13:00;1;115;7;3;2;4;0;0;2;0;0;1;91;9;2;2;7;0;0;1;0;0;134;113;247
10.01.2017;14:00;0;93;7;2;4;6;2;0;1;0;0;1;107;5;3;3;4;0;0;1;0;3;115;127;242
10.01.2017;15:00;0;126;7;1;2;7;1;0;1;0;0;0;110;2;1;3;9;2;0;3;0;0;145;130;275
10.01.2017;16:00;0;133;4;1;2;10;0;1;3;0;0;0;114;6;4;0;7;0;0;2;0;0;154;133;287
10.01.2017;17:00;0;111;7;6;4;5;1;0;1;0;0;0;118;7;1;2;8;0;1;0;0;0;135;137;272
10.01.2017;18:00;0;78;6;1;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;84;2;2;0;0;0;1;2;0;0;87;91;178
10.01.2017;19:00;0;51;5;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;60;1;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;58;64;122
10.01.2017;20:00;0;39;1;2;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;54;2;2;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;44;59;103
10.01.2017;21:00;0;32;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;34;2;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;33;39;72
10.01.2017;22:00;0;22;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;25;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;23;26;49
10.01.2017;23:00;0;22;2;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;21;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;26;22;48
11.01.2017;00:00;0;9;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;9;6;15
11.01.2017;01:00;0;6;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;7;0;7
11.01.2017;02:00;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;4;5
11.01.2017;03:00;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;2
11.01.2017;04:00;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;2
11.01.2017;05:00;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;7;5;12
11.01.2017;06:00;0;8;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;9;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;8;12;20
11.01.2017;07:00;0;35;3;0;0;1;0;0;2;0;0;0;52;9;0;1;1;0;0;3;0;0;41;66;107
11.01.2017;08:00;0;80;2;4;2;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;99;3;4;1;9;0;1;2;0;0;95;119;214
11.01.2017;09:00;0;78;3;2;2;8;0;0;1;0;0;0;84;4;4;2;7;0;0;0;0;3;94;104;198
11.01.2017;10:00;0;61;6;6;4;9;0;0;1;0;0;1;80;10;3;3;7;0;0;0;0;0;87;104;191
11.01.2017;11:00;0;83;6;3;1;5;0;0;2;0;0;0;63;6;4;4;5;0;0;0;0;0;100;82;182
11.01.2017;12:00;1;96;7;3;3;13;0;1;0;0;0;0;91;8;4;2;13;0;0;0;0;1;124;119;243
11.01.2017;13:00;0;86;11;4;1;3;0;0;2;0;0;0;80;7;3;2;5;0;0;1;0;0;107;98;205
11.01.2017;14:00;0;100;6;3;2;6;0;0;1;0;0;0;92;4;2;4;8;0;0;1;0;0;118;111;229
11.01.2017;15:00;0;109;8;1;2;4;0;0;1;0;0;1;100;4;2;2;4;0;0;3;0;0;125;116;241
11.01.2017;16:00;0;118;4;2;1;4;0;0;4;0;0;0;108;7;1;2;6;0;1;3;0;0;133;128;261
11.01.2017;17:00;0;117;5;4;2;6;0;1;1;0;0;0;116;5;2;2;4;0;0;0;0;0;136;129;265
11.01.2017;18:00;0;93;2;2;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;97;4;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;98;104;202
11.01.2017;19:00;0;51;3;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;56;3;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;55;60;115
11.01.2017;20:00;0;36;3;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;54;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;40;55;95
11.01.2017;21:00;0;38;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;35;1;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;1;39;40;79
11.01.2017;22:00;0;21;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;19;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;23;20;43
11.01.2017;23:00;0;16;2;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;13;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;19;14;33
12.01.2017;00:00;0;11;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;11;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;11;12;23
12.01.2017;01:00;0;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;7;2;9
12.01.2017;02:00;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;1;3
12.01.2017;03:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3
12.01.2017;04:00;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;1;3
12.01.2017;05:00;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;8;4;12
12.01.2017;06:00;0;6;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;8;2;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;6;12;18
12.01.2017;07:00;0;43;2;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;57;7;1;0;2;0;0;4;0;0;47;71;118
12.01.2017;08:00;0;74;5;3;1;6;0;0;0;0;0;0;103;6;4;1;6;0;0;2;0;1;89;123;212
12.01.2017;09:00;0;66;7;6;3;4;0;0;1;0;0;0;68;7;3;1;6;0;0;1;0;2;87;88;175
12.01.2017;10:00;0;68;6;7;4;7;0;1;0;0;0;0;76;10;4;3;5;0;0;0;0;0;93;98;191
12.01.2017;11:00;0;86;8;4;2;4;0;0;2;0;1;0;70;6;6;2;5;0;0;0;0;1;107;90;197
12.01.2017;12:00;0;97;6;4;3;9;0;0;0;0;0;0;66;4;3;4;10;0;0;1;0;1;119;89;208
12.01.2017;13:00;0;76;12;7;3;6;0;0;1;0;0;0;83;5;5;7;6;0;1;1;0;0;105;108;213
12.01.2017;14:00;0;97;3;4;5;6;0;0;1;0;1;0;100;12;2;4;7;1;0;1;0;1;117;128;245
12.01.2017;15:00;1;105;8;4;1;4;0;0;1;0;0;0;94;2;2;1;5;0;0;3;0;0;124;107;231
12.01.2017;16:00;0;131;7;1;2;4;1;0;4;0;0;0;110;8;1;2;5;0;0;2;0;1;150;129;279
12.01.2017;17:00;0;118;5;3;2;5;0;2;1;0;0;0;100;4;2;1;5;0;1;1;0;0;136;114;250
12.01.2017;18:00;0;73;5;3;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;87;6;0;0;1;0;0;2;0;0;83;96;179
12.01.2017;19:00;0;43;4;2;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;63;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;51;64;115
12.01.2017;20:00;0;48;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;51;1;1;0;1;1;0;1;0;0;51;56;107
12.01.2017;21:00;0;37;0;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;33;1;0;0;0;0;0;4;0;0;40;38;78
12.01.2017;22:00;0;22;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;28;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;23;29;52
12.01.2017;23:00;0;25;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;13;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;27;14;41
13.01.2017;00:00;0;9;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;9;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;10;9;19
13.01.2017;01:00;0;9;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;9;1;10
13.01.2017;02:00;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1
13.01.2017;03:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1
13.01.2017;04:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1
13.01.2017;05:00;0;4;0;1;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;6;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;8;8;16
13.01.2017;06:00;0;6;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;6;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;7;9;16
13.01.2017;07:00;0;38;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;60;10;0;0;1;0;0;3;0;0;41;74;115
13.01.2017;08:00;0;60;2;0;1;2;0;0;0;0;1;0;94;6;4;2;8;1;0;2;0;1;66;118;184
13.01.2017;09:00;0;65;10;1;3;6;0;0;1;0;1;0;64;3;6;0;7;0;0;0;0;0;87;80;167
13.01.2017;10:00;0;79;10;3;3;6;0;0;1;0;0;0;78;12;5;1;7;0;0;0;0;0;102;103;205
13.01.2017;11:00;0;97;9;3;8;7;0;0;2;0;0;0;77;13;4;1;9;0;0;0;0;0;126;104;230
13.01.2017;12:00;0;80;9;5;6;9;0;0;0;0;0;0;86;5;4;3;10;0;0;2;0;0;109;110;219
13.01.2017;13:00;0;90;4;1;1;8;0;0;2;0;1;0;83;5;6;3;3;0;0;2;0;0;107;102;209
13.01.2017;14:00;0;99;8;2;2;5;0;0;1;0;0;0;98;7;0;1;7;0;0;1;0;1;117;115;232
13.01.2017;15:00;0;90;9;3;4;5;0;0;1;0;0;0;83;12;2;0;6;0;0;3;0;1;112;107;219
13.01.2017;16:00;0;118;9;5;0;3;0;0;4;0;0;0;97;3;2;1;4;0;0;2;0;0;139;109;248
13.01.2017;17:00;0;126;10;2;1;4;0;0;1;0;0;0;91;4;2;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;144;99;243
13.01.2017;18:00;0;72;1;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;88;4;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;75;93;168
13.01.2017;19:00;0;43;4;2;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;58;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;52;59;111
13.01.2017;20:00;0;44;3;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;52;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;49;54;103
13.01.2017;21:00;0;40;2;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;35;3;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;43;40;83
13.01.2017;22:00;0;17;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;24;2;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;19;27;46
13.01.2017;23:00;0;20;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;23;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1;20;25;45
14.01.2017;00:00;0;15;1;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;11;0;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;19;13;32
14.01.2017;01:00;0;10;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;3;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;11;4;15
14.01.2017;02:00;0;2;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;5;8
14.01.2017;03:00;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;2;5
14.01.2017;04:00;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;2
14.01.2017;05:00;0;2;1;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;3;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;4;9
14.01.2017;06:00;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;8;2;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;4;12;16
14.01.2017;07:00;0;14;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;38;2;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;15;43;58
14.01.2017;08:00;0;30;1;4;0;2;0;1;0;0;0;0;46;3;3;0;5;0;0;2;0;0;38;59;97
14.01.2017;09:00;0;47;9;2;1;8;0;0;1;0;0;0;40;6;4;0;6;0;0;1;0;0;68;57;125
14.01.2017;10:00;0;68;6;3;3;9;0;1;0;0;1;0;55;2;1;2;7;0;1;0;0;1;91;69;160
14.01.2017;11:00;0;81;5;3;2;5;0;0;1;0;0;0;50;3;5;2;6;0;0;0;0;0;97;66;163
14.01.2017;12:00;0;79;5;2;4;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;72;3;2;0;10;1;1;0;0;0;93;89;182
14.01.2017;13:00;0;94;5;3;1;3;1;0;1;0;0;0;74;3;1;0;3;0;1;0;0;0;108;82;190
14.01.2017;14:00;0;79;3;2;2;9;0;0;1;0;0;0;99;2;0;2;11;0;0;2;0;0;96;116;212
14.01.2017;15:00;0;96;3;1;3;8;0;0;0;0;1;0;82;1;1;1;6;0;0;1;0;0;112;92;204
14.01.2017;16:00;2;99;3;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;2;90;7;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;107;102;209
14.01.2017;17:00;0;92;2;1;0;2;0;0;2;0;0;0;99;5;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;99;105;204
14.01.2017;18:00;0;70;2;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;86;1;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;74;89;163
14.01.2017;19:00;0;63;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;70;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;65;72;137
14.01.2017;20:00;0;40;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;45;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;42;45;87
14.01.2017;21:00;0;40;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;28;3;1;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;41;34;75
14.01.2017;22:00;0;27;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;31;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;29;32;61
14.01.2017;23:00;0;24;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;18;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;26;18;44
```

Comment: Providing a small sample of your data (using `dput()`) would be a great help, and would make this a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The x-axis in your graph provides a clue that your dates are not formatted correctly, but it's impossible to know if we don't have data to work with.

Comment: The `dput` function will convert an R object into a format that can be copied and pasted as text. So just call `dput(daily_data[1:30,])`  (or however many rows are needed to reproduce your problem) and paste that into the question. Links to data are strongly discouraged (both for security concerns and because they will break eventually, making this question useless to future users)

Comment: For future reference, [here is how to provide R data for your questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stack-overflow/315888#315888)

Comment: Screenshots are no good either. Sorry for seeming so picky about this (I know we're probably getting pretty annoying by now), but the reason we need an example of your data as text is so we can paste it into R and replicate (and try to solve) your problem. If you give a screenshot there's nothing we can do with that.

Comment: @Thom Thanks! That's great. Thanks for taking the time to make improvements

Comment: Ok, last comment on the question - not all of this data is relevent to your problem. A dataframe with just the date and time, and the output you want to plot against is all that's needed. The other 26 columns aren't relevant to the problem and don't need to be included. You also only need to include as many observations as is required to get your point across - in your case, maybe 20 or 30. But I echo @divibisan in saying thanks for taking on the learning opportunity to ask good questions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you have, if you look at your data closely, is actually that you have several values per day (i.e., hourly data), but `as.Date()` produces only a date with no time. Therefore, the figure you're plotting is correct because you're plotting all values on the same day together.

To fix this, you need to produce a column of the hourly (date and time) data to use in your plots. I am particularly fond of the `lubridate` package, so I've used that here to help:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

daily_data$datetime <- paste(daily_data$datum, daily_data$sat, sep=" ")
daily_data$Date <- dmy_hm(daily_data$datetime)

ggplot(daily_data, aes(Date, total)) + 
  geom_line() +
  ylab("opterecenje") + 
  xlab("") # total is the column with numbers that represent some data for a given date.
```

[image]